# C# Hightlight DataGrid row based if value matches textbox value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

How do I highlight a datagrid row based off the value in textbox2?

Ultimately when a matching value is found in Column 2 the QTY field (column 3) on that corresponding row will need change by -1 for each QR Code scanned by the End user. Once the QTY value reaches 0 the the row will need to be highlighted Green.

I can't just get it to work have tried a few different ways of writing the foreach section but no luck

My code is as below:

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
         iCBOMHDataGridView.DataSource = iCBOMHBindingSource;

            string input = textBox2.Text;
            string output = "";
            textBox2.Text = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\d{4}|[A-z]{2}[0-9]{5},|,|,|\d{|[0-9]{4}/....|\d{1,}\/\d{2,2}\/\d{4}|\s.........|\s|,|,|,|\d*?.$|[*?:/]\n|\r|\r\n", output);

               foreach (DataGridViewRow row in iCBOMHDataGridView.Rows)
               {
                if ((string)row.Cells[2].Value == textBox2.Text)
                    {
                        row.Selected = true;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        row.Selected = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("Part Number doesn't match");
                    }
               }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop inside all cells of that row and set the cell **Style** property. You can create different styles for non-selected and selected rows, then apply these styles as necessary.

Example:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle selectedStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
selectedStyle.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
selectedStyle.ForeColor = Color.OrangeRed;

DataGridViewCellStyle defaultStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
defaultStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
defaultStyle.ForeColor = Control.DefaultForeColor;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in iCBOMHDataGridView.Rows)
{
    if ((string)row.Cells[2].Value == textBox2.Text)
    {
        row.Selected = true;

        if(Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()) > 0)
            row.Cells[2].Value = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) - 1;
    }

    if (Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()) <= 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell col in row.Cells.AsParallel())
            col.Style = selectedStyle;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell col in row.Cells.AsParallel())
            col.Style = defaultStyle;
    }  
}
```

If you do not want to loop through the cells, you can simply change the *DataRow.DefaultCellStyle* property of each row. But this will limit your customization options.

Comment: Ultimately when a matching value is found the QTY field on that corresponding row will need change by -1 for each QR Code scanned by the End user. Once the QTY value reaches 0 the the row will need to be highlighted Green.

Comment: Then apply the style only after a condition checking if the QTY column is zero. *if ((string)row.Cells[cQTY.Name].Value <= 0)*